# How to enable support for closed caption tracks on custom chromecast receiver?

Tags: chromecast, google-cast

I found an example on [github for closedcaptions on custom receiver](https://github.com/googlecast/CastClosedCaptioning-chrome) which is about two years old. This example uses sender-receiver communication messageBus to send message to receiver to add a track element to show captions. At that time, chromecast's default media receiver did not support caption track. But as of today, it supports it which can be enabled using [chrome.cast.media.Media.editTracksInfo](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/reference/chrome/chrome.cast.media.Media#editTracksInfo). I tried using editTracksInfo API method to enable captions on my custom receiver which is built using Media Player Library, but it did not work. Can someone please confirm if I still will have to use messageBus to tell my receiver app to create/insert track elements to add captions support to my receiver or can I leverage MPL to automatically do it?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need any custom message; a fully UX compliant [receiver sample](https://github.com/googlecast/Cast-Player-Sample) that supports Closed Captions is available on our GitHub repo. You can use that receiver as the base for your own or you can read through it to see how MPL is utilized to provide closed captions for adaptive media. If you have a simple mp4 + side-loaded vtt file, then MPL doesn't get involved. On the sender side, we now support tracks through the SDK directly; if you want to see a sample of that, take a look at [CCL](https://github.com/googlecast/CastCompanionLibrary-android).